# Do RegisterEntityType from class DbModelBuilder method allows you to add 2 times the same type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

using System.Data.Entity;

I added 2 times the same type to RegisterEntityType, and only creates one table.
It look likes enters table configuration methods twice for this type but returns only one table.

```
DbModelBuilder modelBuilder;
foreach (var type in types.Models)
{
      Type modelType = type;
      modelBuilder.RegisterEntityType(modelType);
}
```

Is it not possible to add the same type twice or is it probably wrong to configure the table?

Comment: There is a mapping file (edmx) in Entity that links the tables i the database to the c# classes.  Just adding a type without changing the model will not work.

Comment: @jdweng I was given a task in which I would create dynamically several the same tables based on the configuration file and I have to only change the column names and table name. So I can't do it like this?

Comment: Do you have the same database?  Does the mapping change?

Comment: @jdweng This is to create a single database. For example, I have an ArchiveModel, it has 20 properties of the byte [] type. And the user in the configuration file sets the names for these columns and the name of the table, he can create several such tables. But the mapping doesn't change.